# Zend - Storing Session data in a database

Tags: php, zend-framework

Looking for an example of storing session data in a database, using the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Zend themselves, on saving session data with a custom session handler: http://devzone.zend.com/article/141

Otherwise, from within the Zend framework try the following information: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable?showComments=false

Answer (score 3):

You will want to look into hooking up the Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable

Of which you can find direct examples/guidance in the framework manual

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.savehandler.dbtable.html